# Easy_install fails installing lxml with gcc 4.2.1 on Mac

Tags: macos, gcc, lxml, easy-install

I am attempting to install lxml on my mac (OSX Yosemite 10.10.5) to use with BeautifulSoup.

```
easy_install lxml
```

However, it fails to run and looks like it's searching for the wrong version of gcc:

```
unable to execute gcc-4.0: No such file or directory
Compile failed: command 'gcc-4.0' failed with exit status 1 /var/folders/zt/hvzclr2s00scp1ppzyr2j6k40000gn/T/easy_install-yDugbm/lxml-3.6.0/temp/xmlXPathInitV0OYZj.c:2:1: warning: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int]
main (int argc, char **argv) {
^
1 warning generated.
ld: library not found for -lgcc_s.10.5
```

Based on similar questions on SO I've already tried:

- Running `xcode-select --install` and have gcc version 4.2.1 currently
- Linking specific gcc versions to /usr/bin/gcc. `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.2`and `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.0`. The 4.0 link solved this issue, but spewed out lots of sytanx-related errors (`error: Unsupported architecture`, `error: unknown type name '__int64_t'`, etc.), which isn't surprising because it's a different version.

As requested, here is the output of `easy_install lxml` with the gcc-4.0 alias:

```
Searching for lxml
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/lxml/
Best match: lxml 3.6.0
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/l/lxml/lxml-3.6.0.tar.gz#md5=5957cc384bd6e83934be35c057ec03b6
Processing lxml-3.6.0.tar.gz
Writing /var/folders/zt/hvzclr2s00scp1ppzyr2j6k40000gn/T/easy_install-R7v3TQ/lxml-3.6.0/setup.cfg
Running lxml-3.6.0/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /var/folders/zt/hvzclr2s00scp1ppzyr2j6k40000gn/T/easy_install-R7v3TQ/lxml-3.6.0/egg-dist-tmp-u8jVqK
Building lxml version 3.6.0.
Building without Cython.
Using build configuration of libxslt 1.1.28
Building against libxml2/libxslt in the following directory: /opt/local/lib
In file included from src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:82:
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/Python.h:19:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/6.1.0/include/limits.h:37:
In file included from /usr/include/limits.h:63:
/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h:680:2: error: Unsupported architecture
#error Unsupported architecture
 ^
In file included from src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:82:
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/Python.h:19:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/6.1.0/include/limits.h:37:
In file included from /usr/include/limits.h:64:
/usr/include/machine/limits.h:8:2: error: architecture not supported
#error architecture not supported
 ^
In file included from src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:82:
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/Python.h:33:
In file included from /usr/include/stdio.h:67:
In file included from /usr/include/_types.h:27:
In file included from /usr/include/sys/_types.h:33:
/usr/include/machine/_types.h:34:2: error: architecture not supported
#error architecture not supported
 ^
In file included from src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:82:
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/Python.h:33:
In file included from /usr/include/stdio.h:67:
In file included from /usr/include/_types.h:27:
/usr/include/sys/_types.h:55:9: error: unknown type name '__int64_t'
typedef __int64_t       __darwin_blkcnt_t;      /* total blocks */
        ^
/usr/include/sys/_types.h:56:9: error: unknown type name '__int32_t'
typedef __int32_t       __darwin_blksize_t;     /* preferred block size */
        ^
/usr/include/sys/_types.h:57:9: error: unknown type name '__int32_t'
typedef __int32_t       __darwin_dev_t;         /* dev_t */
        ^
/usr/include/sys/_types.h:60:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'
typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_gid_t;         /* [???] process and group IDs */
        ^
/usr/include/sys/_types.h:61:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'
typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_id_t;          /* [XSI] pid_t, uid_t, or gid_t*/
        ^
/usr/include/sys/_types.h:62:9: error: unknown type name '__uint64_t'
typedef __uint64_t      __darwin_ino64_t;       /* [???] Used for 64 bit inodes */
        ^
/usr/include/sys/_types.h:66:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'
typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_ino_t;         /* [???] Used for inodes */
        ^
/usr/include/sys/_types.h:68:9: error: unknown type name '__darwin_natural_t'
typedef __darwin_natural_t __darwin_mach_port_name_t; /* Used by mach */
        ^
/usr/include/sys/_types.h:70:9: error: unknown type name '__uint16_t'
typedef __uint16_t      __darwin_mode_t;        /* [???] Some file attributes */
        ^
/usr/include/sys/_types.h:71:9: error: unknown type name '__int64_t'
typedef __int64_t       __darwin_off_t;         /* [???] Used for file sizes */
        ^
/usr/include/sys/_types.h:72:9: error: unknown type name '__int32_t'
typedef __int32_t       __darwin_pid_t;         /* [???] process and group IDs */
        ^
/usr/include/sys/_types.h:73:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'
typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_sigset_t;      /* [???] signal set */
        ^
/usr/include/sys/_types.h:74:9: error: unknown type name '__int32_t'
typedef __int32_t       __darwin_suseconds_t;   /* [???] microseconds */
        ^
/usr/include/sys/_types.h:75:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'
typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_uid_t;         /* [???] user IDs */
        ^
/usr/include/sys/_types.h:76:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'
typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_useconds_t;    /* [???] microseconds */
        ^
In file included from src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:82:
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/Python.h:33:
In file included from /usr/include/stdio.h:71:
/usr/include/sys/_types/_va_list.h:31:9: error: unknown type name '__darwin_va_list'; did you mean '__builtin_va_list'?
typedef __darwin_va_list va_list;
        ^
note: '__builtin_va_list' declared here
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
20 errors generated.
Compile failed: command 'gcc-4.0' failed with exit status 1
/var/folders/zt/hvzclr2s00scp1ppzyr2j6k40000gn/T/easy_install-R7v3TQ/lxml-3.6.0/temp/xmlXPathInitr479pk.c:2:1: warning: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int]
main (int argc, char **argv) {
^
1 warning generated.
ld: library not found for -lgcc_s.10.5
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
*********************************************************************************
Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. Is libxml2 installed?
Perhaps try: xcode-select --install
*********************************************************************************
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'gcc-4.0' failed with exit status 1
```

This is the output from running `pip install --upgrade pip`: 
(**UPDATE**: Resolved by upgrading Python to version 2.7.11. Version must be 2.7.9 or higher)

> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/*vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl*.py:315:
>   SNIMissingWarning: An HTTPS request has been made, but the SNI
>   (Subject Name Indication) extension to TLS is not available on this
>   platform. This may cause the server to present an incorrect TLS
>   certificate, which can cause validation failures. For more
>   information, see
>   https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#snimissingwarning.
>   SNIMissingWarning
>   /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/*vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl*.py:120:
>   InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available.
>   This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause
>   certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see
>   https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
>   InsecurePlatformWarning Could not fetch URL
>   https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming
>   the ssl certificate: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:499: error:0D0890A1:asn1
>   encoding routines:ASN1_verify:unknown message digest algorithm -
>   skipping Requirement already up-to-date: pip in
>   /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.1-py2.7.egg
>   /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/*vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl*.py:120:
>   InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available.
>   This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause
>   certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see
>   https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
>   InsecurePlatformWarning

Any clue how to properly configure/use my easy_install?

Comment: Any change you could try installing with `pip` instead?

Comment: I don't see the syntax errors listed that you mention, but I notice a library problem.

Comment: I started to look at pip and installed it with `easy_install pip`, but running `pip install <anything>`, including the security updates suggested in other posts, returns errors. (i.e. SNIMissingWarning, InsecurePlatformWarning)

Comment: Edited the description to add some of those syntax errors. I can put the full trace if you want, but it's rather long.

Comment: Those errors are a bit surprising (they seem to originate because of a missing -std=c99 option to the compiler), because I grepped through the lxml source code, and no int64 pops up. If you can port a bit of the traceback for e.g. that particular syntax error, so that it includes the full path name, that may help.

Comment: You might be able to get rid of the pip issues by (trying to) upgrade pip: `pip install --upgrade pip`. Currently, pip 8.1.1 is around. (Also note that easy_install is generally not used anymore, and preferably should be avoided.)

Comment: Lastly, I can mention how I got lxml installed: I used Homebrew to install an up-to-date version of Python (2 or 3, your choice; they can coexist), installed the libxml2 and libxslt dependencies with Homebrew, then installed lxml with pip. Since all executables and libraries live in /usr/local (use e.g. /usr/local/bin/pip), it's safely out of the way of the system.

Comment: @Evert Thank you, I'll give those a try. I have Python 2.7 installed currently.  Unfortunately `pip install --upgrade pip`, also returned the errors noted above, so perhaps I need to reinstall it via a different method.

Comment: For the pip errors, you can have a look at the [two relevant sections on the urllib3 documentation](http://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning). Both section suggest to upgrade Python; I would not do that (that is, not upgrade the *system* Python; the Homebrew solution is definitely safe in /usr/local). It also suggests that installing pip differently (e.g. with [`get-pip.py`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/#installing-with-get-pip-py) will not help, since it's Python that's the problem for pip.

Comment: Btw, could also add a longer section/context on the syntax errors? That's where I'm curious about the path names that causes those `__int64_t` etc errors.

Comment: @Evert, that section of the urllib3 docs had the answer: "InsecurePlatformWarning... versions of Python earlier than 2.7.9". I upgraded to the latest Python 2 (2.7.11) and that solved the pip install errors.

Comment: This seems to have diverged into two questions now 1. Errors with easy_install and 2. Errors with pip; but both are related to downloading lxml. Would you have a reccomendation for how to restructure the question to make it more useful for future visitors?

Comment: The "unsupported architecture" issue is problematic; not sure what's going on there. It's at least somewhat searchable (add "os x" and "int64" to the search words, for example), but not always helpful (e.g., http://superuser.com/questions/800168/why-do-i-get-unsupported-architecture-errors-trying-to-install-a-python-librar ), but lxml 3.6.0 is very recent, so I wouldn't expect that.

Comment: As for the 2 questions in one (happens a lot): you could take the pip issue out of this question, create a standalone question about that, and answer it yourself. It may even be a duplicate; I haven't searched, but you could search SO on those specific warnings.

Comment: Practically, what versions of lxslt and libxml2 do you have installed? I don't see any header of those libraries included in the compilation errors listed, but it might be an issue.